Is there a way to make VS Code to highlight only the last between Ctrl-F and Ctrl-Shift-F searches?
In VS Code, we can search a string in a file using Ctrl-F and search through the workspace using Ctrl-Shift-F. Both versions highlight all the matches. That is annoying because when you created the second search you most likely already switched your focus from the first and does not care about its results. Is there any way to configure VS Code so the Ctrl-F highlights disappear when you have the results from a Ctrl-Shift-F and vice-versa?
If there is no way to configure that, could anyone please point to an extension API point that could manage that?

If there's a setting for this, I don't know it. But I know how to cheat: Whenever you go to one thing, clear the other thing.
{
    "key": "ctrl+f",
    "command": "runCommands",
    "args": { "commands": [
        "search.action.clearSearchResults",
        "actions.find",
    ]},
    "when": "editorFocus || editorIsOpen",
},
{
    "key": "ctrl+shift+f",
    "command": "runCommands",
    "args": { "commands": [
        { "command": "editor.actions.findWithArgs", "args": { "searchString": "" }},
        "closeFindWidget",
        "workbench.action.findInFiles",
    ]},
},

Note on search.action.clearSearchResults: For some reason this only does anything if search view is focused, but that's fine since matches for the search view seem to only get highlighted when it is focused.

@nfgf notice that I edited my answer post. your previous comment (which you seem to have just reposted) was removed because after I edited, it was no longer needed and I flagged it for removal.
